# jQuery search from the begining of input of value in first column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple dynamic table search script

What I'm trying to figure out is, how do I make it search from the begining of the value?

eg. I only want it to show the row with the word london in it if one were to search it as lo or lon, currently if you type in on, or ondon it'll return true.

also with this example, how do I force it to only search the first column of each row?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#search input').keyup(function() {
   var text = $(this).val();
    if (text != null) {
     $('table tbody tr').hide();
      $('table tbody tr').filter(':contains("' + text + '")').show();
    }
  });
  

});
```

```css
th {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 25px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search">
  <input type="text" placeholder="search somethingn" />
</div>

<table id="items">
  <thead>
    <th>item</th>
    <th>something else</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>london</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>new york</td>
      <td>test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8p4w62pe/

Comment: Nice question! I wish more people posted questions with fiddles + minimal example code and not half their project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in startsWith selector, but you can write your own:

```
 $.extend($.expr[":"], {
   "startsWith": function(elem, i, data, set) {
       var text = $.trim($(elem).text()),term = data[3];
       return text.indexOf(term) === 0;
   },
 });
```

You will also need to change your selector to select the `td` (not the `tr`). To only select the first `td` add `:first-child` to the selector. Then change the `show()` to apply to the parent using `parent()`:

```
$('table tbody tr td:first-child').filter(':startsWith("' + text + '")').parent().show();
```

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "startsWith": function(elem, i, data, set) {
        var text = $.trim($(elem).text()),term = data[3];
        return text.indexOf(term) === 0;
    },
  });

  $('#search input').keyup(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (text != null) {
       $('table tbody tr').hide();
       $('table tbody tr td:first-child').filter(':startsWith("' + text + '")').parent().show();
    }
  });
});
```

[Working JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3orgtyd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop each of the row, get the first column and then hide the whole row if substring can't be found

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#search input').keyup(function() {
        var text = $(this).val();
        if (text != null) {
            $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
                if($(this).find("td:first-child").html().indexOf(text) === -1) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }    
            });   
        }
    });
});
```